# How to one hot encode unordered discrete data in python?

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding

## Problem

There seems no easy way to one-hot-encode data that has no order. My question is, what is the best way to one-hot-encode values that have no particular order? And if there is no standardised way to do this, why should one-hot-encoded features be ordered?

### Example

I am trying to one-hot-encode a set of features where the values are custom objects. My object looks like this:

```
class MyObject(object)
    def __init__(self, identity):
        self.identity = identity

    def __hash__(self):
        return self.identity

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.identity == other.identity
```

In this setting each instance of MyObject can be compared on equality. Suppose we have the following list of objects:

```
objects = [MyObject(0), MyObject(1), MyObject(0)]
```

The function `set(objects)` yields a set of 2 objects, namely `MyObject(0)` and `MyObject(1)`. This is indeed the behaviour that I expect. Therefore, when I try to one-hot-encode this data, I would expect something in the form of:

```
index   MyObject_0, MyObject_1
    0            1           0
    1            0           1
    2            1           0
```

However, all solutions that I tried require data to be one-hot-encoded to have some sort of order, whereas that is undefined in my case. I think it should still be possible to have a one-hot-encoding if the order is undefined as in that case it does not matter which one-hot-encoded feature is before the other.

## Attempted solutions

### Pandas dataframe

My first attempted solution was using pandas' `get_dummies()` function.

```
import pandas as pd

objects   = [MyObject(0), MyObject(1), MyObject(0)]
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'MyObjectFeature': objects})
dummies   = pd.get_dummies(dataframe)
```

However, this example gives a TypeError:

```
TypeError: 'values' is not ordered, please explicitly specify the categories order by passing in a categories argument.
```

### Scikit-learn LabelEncoder & OneHotEncoder

My second attempt was using Scikit-learn's `LabelEncoder` to encode the values before putting them into a `OneHotEncoder` object. However, in the `LabelEncoder` the same problem as using Pandas dataframes arises.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing  import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder

objects = [MyObject(0), MyObject(1), MyObject(0)]
encoder = LabelEncoder()
dummies = encoder.fit_transform(objects)
```

This example also gives a TypeError:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'MyObject' and 'MyObject'
```

### Custom solution

I also created my own `UnorderedLabelEncoder` object to encode labels without requiring an order. This works fine, but I would like to know if there is a standard solution to my problem, i.e. using well-known libraries. Or if this is not the case, I would like to know if there is a reason for requiring ordered features?

```
class UnorderedLabelEncoder(object):

    def __init__(self):
        """ CustomLabelEncoder is capable of handling any
            hashable object including None values.
            """
        self.classes_ = dict()

    def fit(self, y):
        """ Fit label encoder.

            Parameters
            ----------
            y : array-like of shape (n_samples,)
                Target values.

            Returns
            -------
            self : returns an instance of self.
            """
        self.classes_ = {o:i for i, o in enumerate(set(y))}
        return self

    def fit_transform(self, y):
        """ Fit label encoder and return encoded labels.

            Parameters
            ----------
            y : array-like of shape [n_samples]
                Target values.

            Returns
            -------
            y : array-like of shape [n_samples]
        """
        self.fit(y)
        return self.transform(y)

    def transform(self, y):
        """ Transform labels to normalized encoding.

            Parameters
            ----------
            y : array-like of shape [n_samples]
                Target values.

            Returns
            -------
            y : array-like of shape [n_samples]
        """
        return np.array([self.classes_.get(x, -1) for x in y])
```

## Question

Just to reiterate: My question is, what is the best way to one-hot-encode values that have no particular order? And if there is no standardised way to do this, why should one-hot-encoded features be ordered?

Answer (score 2):

I would say that if the values do not have an intrinsic order (partial order) stemming from its type then you can define order artificially (something alike an artificial primary key in databases). Then this is the order that you impose on the data and going forwards you can use any method available for ordered data (as if there had been a [partial] order in the first place).

Comment: Hi sophros, yes that is indeed true. In my example I could easily impose an order by implementing <, <=, >=, >. However, in my actual program, I do not use the `MyObject` object as in this example, but an object that I do not control. Thus, I am unable (unless hacking around this) to add methods for imposing the order directly in the class. Do you know if there is any way of imposing an order in that case?

Comment: Why don't you [decorate](https://www.thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/) your class to add ordering operators if this is what you are after here?

Comment: Correct. @ThijsvanEde This is what the libraries (pandas and scikit) do. They only create numbers from categories (temporarily) because numbers can be handled easily and fast. After that they will return data as you expect.

Comment: @Thijs van Ede - since it helped could you please accept the answer?

Comment: It helped, but it didn't answer my question because introducing an artificial order should not be a necessity for one-hot encoding.

Comment: You either have an intrinsic order or artificial one - to me there is no other way to know which dimension to be "hot encoded". Could you please share what I am missing here?

Comment: Suppose you have a 1D array of three values: ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c']. If you were to one-hot encode this, all algorithms that I know of require an ordering to put these in the right dimensions. If we'd look at an x, y, z, system you could map the 'a' to the x dimension, 'b' to the y and 'c' to the z. My point is that in some cases you don't care to which dimension it is mapped as long as it is mapped to some dimension. That is why I don't understand why there has to be an intrinsic order as to me it would be the same as mapping e.g. 'a' to y, 'b' to x and 'c' to z.

Comment: I agree with everything but the last sentence. You can pick _any_ assignment but there has to be one chosen. It is arbitrary which assignment you are going to pick. It does not matter. But the fact that there has to be one picked is non-disputable. Also, it is easiest to pick the one that is somewhat "natural" but it is not a must to pick this one.